# The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, expression

Hi i am trying to create Row widget with 3 children 2 textbutton and text widget, 2 textbitton if shown based on a condition but the issue is when i add  text widget inside that ,its showing the error, somebody please help me with  this ? why its showing

Error showing: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

```
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    (bannerData.data!.userWeek == 4 ||
            bannerData.data!.iconWeekwise![index].weekStatus ==
                'One week ago')
        ? Container()
        : TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              _pageController.previousPage(
                  duration: _kDuration, curve: _kCurve);

              bannerDataProvider.decrementWeek();
            },
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/images/arrow_back.svg",
              height: 15,
            )),
    Text(bannerData.data!.iconWeekwise![index].weekStatus.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: systemFontSize(SizeConfiguration.size14),
                fontFamily: "GeoBook",
                color: ColorConstants.textBlack,
                fontWeight: FontWeight
                    .w600))(bannerData.data!.userWeek == 40 ||
            bannerData.data!.iconWeekwise![index].weekStatus ==
                'One week ahead')
        ? Container()
        : TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              _pageController.nextPage(
                  duration: _kDuration, curve: _kCurve);

              bannerDataProvider.incrementWeek();
            },
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/images/arrow_forward.svg",
              height: 15,
            ),
          )
  ],
)
```

Comment: This means that u are trying to call something as a function which is not by using `()` after it.... usually the line number is provided in the error, which helps to identify where

Comment: it would be easier if you point the specific part

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional `if` inside children, and return single child widget easily

```dart
children:[
  if(isTrue) buildTrueWidget(),
]
```

If you like to use else state it will be

```dart
children:[
  if(isTrue) buildTrueWidget() /// there will be no `,`
  else buildFalseWidget(),
]
```

Now if you like to return multiple widget, you can use spread operator on list

```dart
children:[
  if(isTrue) 
    ...[ buildTrueWidgetA(),
          buildTrueWidgetB(),
        ],
]
```

Comment: here i am using multiple conditions inside a children widget,children=[((condition1)return widget), textwidget  ,((condition2)return widget)],i can add both conditions inside children but while adding the text widget in between them, its showing the error

Comment: can you point the specific part and condition can be used on parent if it is solo existence

Comment: hi thanks bro for response, i resolved the issue by creating multiple rows for every each widget and rendered

Comment: You may not be needed if you use conditional if with spread operator

Comment: i tried with spread operator, it has thrown some error, so did this method, but i am facing real test , major logical issue,could you help with new question sir?

Comment: I can give a try, if you   share the link

Comment: sure thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618343/flutter-api-inegration-with-provider